# How do I offset the start of a cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a cloth simulation that I'm using to drape some cloth over an object. I'd like to be able to offset the timing of it so that at a certain frame where I'm happy with how it drapes, I can offset that frame to frame one, and then continue the animation from there.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: after applying the cloth modifier and adding a new cloth modifier, you should use alt+A, it resets the simulations. Make sure your new cloth modifier is in the same order in the modifiers panel as the cloth modifier that was then applied

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but I think I get it. Are you trying to create a base simulation which you then make static, and then you add another cloth modifier for details? Or are you just trying to apply it to make it static?

Comment: @TARDISMaker No, not really. So I start with a cloth that I want to drape over an object. I run the simulation for a while until it's settled on the object and stops moving. Let's say it's now on frame 100. I want to take the cloth's state at frame 100 and move it back to frame 1, then continue the simulation from that point. Applying the cloth modifier and adding a new one doesn't give me the desired result; if I do this, the new cloth stretches out far beyond the first cloth's resting position. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Justin Yup. Why do you need to do this? Can you explain what you're expecting out of it? If you just want it to statically rest on the object you can do that.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I'd like to make it so I don't have to go through the first 100(ish) frames of cloth settling before I can start animating the object. My computer isn't terribly fast and every time I play the animation I have to slog through that first part where the cloth is settling.

Comment: First of all, I'd bake the cloth animation, (that will store it into your harddrive), but also, just set the start frame to frame 100. This will make it so that when you press play, it starts playing at frame 100. Note, that if the cloth isn't baked, it will appear as just the original geometry before it was simulated.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I think that solves my problem. If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Alright, will do :)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to write up the answer. I finally got it up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by baking out the simulation. Make sure that disk cache is enabled, this makes sure that the cache is saved to your harddrive.

[image]

Now when you reopen the file, the simulation is already baked out, almost like keyframed animation, so you won't have to replay the animation every time you open the file.

To make the animation start when when you want it to, In the render setting panel, adjust the start and end frames to match.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Workflow**:

1. Bake the the cloth simulation by clicking **Bake** button in *Cloth Cache* panel.
2. Find a folder called `blendchache_[project_file_name]` in the same directory of the .blend project file.
3. Per-frame data were saved here as files named like [some_num]_000001_00.bphys, [some_num]_000002_00.bphys... etc, the mid-section was actually the frame number, e.g. `000001` means frame 1. Now you can simply delete files from 000001 to 000099.
4. Then you can rename the rest files to [some_num]_000001_00.bphys, [some_num]_000002_00.bphys, etc. (There are many free and handy file rename tools online for download, to do the renaming work in a flash)

You needn't close the project during the process. You can play the offset simulation right after that.

**Tip**:

This trick can be used to offset other simulation types that generate cached data.

Comment: [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) is cross-platform and for this reason a good choice (IMO).

Comment: That's an interesting way to go about it... I feel like mines a bit simpler, even though it doesn't quite make the simulation go back to frame one (It kind of cheats it), but this is definitely an interesting option.

Comment: Very nice solution. Is there any way to embed the baked frames into the .blend file? I need to send the file to someone and don't want to worry about preserving about directory structure.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Not as I can tell. Maybe a better solution would be to zip them first?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to offset my simulation by X ammount of frames and made this Python script for it. Hopefully, this can help anybody with the same problem:

```
from os import walk
from shutil import copy
from re import search,sub

########################
####### variables ######
offset = -20
old_cache_dir = './old'
new_cache_dir = './new'
#########################

cache_files = []

#Get them filez:
for root,dirs,files in walk(old_cache_dir):
    cache_files = files
    break

for file in cache_files:
    #Get frame numer from the file:
    numero = int(search('(?<=_)\d{6}(?=_)',file).group(0))
    
    #Print for later comparison:
    print(file,'\t',sub('(?<=_)\d{6}(?=_)',str(numero + offset).zfill(6),file))
    
    #Do the actual offseting:
    copy('{}/{}'.format(old_cache_dir,file),'{}/{}'.format(new_cache_dir,sub('(?<=_)\d{6}(?=_)',str(numero + offset).zfill(6),file)))
```